# java program is not getting called by timer itself

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have the below code here and I am trying to execute the whole program by itself on every second by using timer, but it is getting called only once. I called below program on first run by command prompt. Can you guys help me on this?

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        final  Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // task to run goes here
                System.out.println("Hello !!!");
                try {
                    dog677_Copy.main(new String[0]);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1 min .
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    trm.main(new String[0]);
                    tstnew.main(new String[0]);

                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // handle the exception,
                    // in this case by throwing a RuntimeException with ex as cause
                    throw new IllegalStateException("I didn't expect a exception.", ex);
                }
            }
        };

        long delay = 0;
        long intevalPeriod = 1 * 240000;

        // schedules the task to be run in an interval 
        // timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay,intevalPeriod);
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);

        System.out.println("Hello !!!");
    } // end of main
}
```

Comment: where dog677_Copy is defined?

Comment: Where is `dog677_Copy `, `trm`,`tstnew` defined?

Comment: @karthik these programs are defined in same location with complied state

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `timer.cancel()` from `run()` method. According to [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) of `cancel()` method:

> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a timer
>   task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that the
>   ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be
>   performed by this timer.

Comment: @MohitDarmwal I'm happy its helped and if it actually resolved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking checkout mark next to votes. Of course it is optional